# Is $f(g(x_1,x_2,x_3,t),x_1,x_2,x_3)$ a function of 7 variables?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have the function $g:\mathbb R^4 \rightarrow \mathbb R$, where $g(\mathbf x,t)=g(x_1,x_2,x_3,t)$.

I also have the function $f$, defined as
$f(g(\mathbf x,t), \mathbf x)=f(g(x_1,x_2,x_3,t),x_1,x_2,x_3)$

I don't know how to interpret $f$. Is it a function of 7 variables? 
Or is it a function composition in some way?

Comment: Since $g(x,t)\in \mathbb R$ your function $f$ is in $4$ variables and the composition $f(g(x,t),x)$ is also in the variables $x$ and $t$ therefore $4$ variables.

Answer (score 1):

Such a formula can only make sense if $f$ is a function of four arguments. In the formula, the four arguments given are:

- $g(x_1, x_2, x_3, t)$
- $x_1$
- $x_2$
- $x_3$

---

The formula

$$ f(g(x_1,x_2,x_3,t),x_1,x_2,x_3) $$

is not a function; it is a *real number*. It varies jointly with the variables $t, x_1, x_2, x_3$. You could express the dependence by defining a function $h$ of four arguments by

$$ h(a,b,c,d) = f(g(a,b,c,d),a,b,c) $$

so that you have

$$ f(g(x_1,x_2,x_3,t),x_1,x_2,x_3) = h(x_1, x_2, x_3, t)$$

This function $h$ is indeed a composite of $f$ and $g$ in some way.

You could also define a function $k$ of seven arguments by

$$ k(a,b,c,d,u,v,w) = f(g(a,b,c,d),u,v,w) $$

and then you'd have identities

$$ h(a,b,c,d) = k(a,b,c,d,a,b,c) $$
$$ f(g(x_1,x_2,x_3,t),x_1,x_2,x_3) = k(x_1, x_2, x_3, t, x_1, x_2, x_3) $$

This function $k$ is also a composite of $f$ and $g$ in some way.

---

It's also worth noting that in the equation

$$ g(\mathbf{x}, t) = g(x_1, x_2, x_3, t)$$

despite being named by the same letter, the indicated functions on the two sides are *different* functions, although they're different in a way we don't usually acknowledge. And if were paying attention to technicalities, the $g$ on the left can only make sense if it is a function of two arguments — one argument being a real 3-vector and one argument being a real number — and the $g$ on the right can only make sense if it is a function of four arguments, all real numbers.